# Attempt to read property "name" on null in relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have the following models and relationships:

```
class Listing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Get the location that owns the listing.
     */
    public function location(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
}

class Location extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'slug';

    /**
     * Get the listing for the location.
     */
    public function listings(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Listing::class);
    }
}
```

And the following pivot table:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('listing_location', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('listing_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('location_id');
        $table->foreign('listing_id')->references('id')->on('listings');
        $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations');
    });
}
```

From my controller I simply return the listings:

```
public function show(): View
{
    return view('pocetna', [
        'featured_listings' => Listing::where('featured', 1)->get()
    ]);
}
```

And in my blade file I loop through them and try to print the location name for each listing:

```
@foreach ($featured_listings as $listing)
    {{ $listing->location->name }}
@endforeach
```

But I get the following error:

```
Attempt to read property "name" on null
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you say "pivot_table", it means `belongsToMany` in both the models, innit?

Comment: Also your code has `n+1`  problem.

Comment: Yeah, ssi-anik is correct; if you have a `pivot` table to link the 2 tables, you don't have a `belongsTo` (`one-to-one`, or `many-to-one`) relationship, you have a `belongsToMany()` (`many-to-many`) relationship. So the relationship is failing to load (but somehow not triggering a SQL-level error?), and `null->name` is not valid. Have a read of the Relationships Documentation and adjust your tables/methods to match: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your pivot table definiton would be wrong in any case, because you defined the same columns with different types. It should look more like this:

```
Schema::create('listing_location', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('listing_id');
    $table->integer('location_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Option 1: One-to-many**

From what is coded in your models I would assume, that you want to represent a one-to-many relationship. So a listing can have many locations, but a location can have only one listing. If that's the case your tables have to be defined as follows.

Listings Table:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Locations Table:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('listing_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Option 2: Many-to-Many**

If you are aiming for a many-to-many relationship, besides from changing your migration, you need to change the function calls in your models to this:

```
class Listing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Get the location that owns the listing.
     */
    public function locations(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class);
    }
}

class Location extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'slug';

    /**
     * Get the listing for the location.
     */
    public function listings(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Listing::class);
    }
}
```